# How to make a cozy-soft border radius

Tags: website-design, borders, adobe-xd, figma

I was on Dribbble and saw this shot. They made this seemingly normal-looking border-radius yet it looks different. How would you achieve this in Figma or AdobeXD? [Shot link](https://dribbble.com/shots/14623432-Music-Streaming-Desktop-app)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this look by clicking the 3 dots near the corner radius in Figma and playing with smoothing, unfortunately, XD can't read corner smoothing, so you won't be able to edit  this as SVG shape in adobe XD

Here's how to do this in Figma:
[image]

Comment: That's nice. +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a normal corner radius.  Looks like the corners have been manually edited. I think that's what you are noticing here and describing as cosy - a hand made look which is naturally less regular.

You could start off with a regular radius, then edit the Bézier curves manually

Sorry, I'm not a Figma user. This example is in XD but I don't see any reason this couldn't also be done in Figma.

[image]

Copy and paste duplicates of the other three corners, and flip them accordingly, then use the Add (aka Union/Unite) boolean operation to make one shape.

[image]

Comment: Can you scale handles in figma (if so then you can do this in one go)

Comment: @joojaa I've no idea. I didn't use Figma. My answer was for XD., But the other answer has a specific answer for Figma.  XD is pretty simple in comparison to other tools. If there is such an option, I haven't found it yet.